# Kotlin for android and static final inner classes

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to rewrite my android app on Kotlin, and I've faces problem while converting ContentProvider contract class.
So I have simple contract class (default stuff like content type and content uris is omitted):

```
public final class Contract {
    public static final class Contacts {
        public static final String NAME = "Name"
        public static final String BIRTH = "Birth"
        public static final String IMAGE = "Image"
    }
}
```

If I understand correctly, in Kotlin we don't have static members. Instead of this, we have "companion objects". So after converting it to Kotlin, I have this code:

```
object BirthdayContract {
    class Contacts : BaseColumns {
        companion object {
            val NAME = "Name"
            val BIRTH = "Birth"
            val IMAGE = "Image"
        }
    }
}
```

But when I'm trying to access fields like Contract.Contacts.NAME, I have error: "NAME has private access". Changing the visibility modifiers gave no effect.
So is there some way to use such contract classes in Kotlin, or it better to keep it in Java?

**UPD** 
I think that I should clarify - my caller code is also in Kotlin.
The problem was in @JvmField annotation. With it, I can access static members directly, without calling getters.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I pasted your `BirthdayContract` into a new Kotlin file, removed ` : BaseColumns` as it does not compile with it, and created a function which accesses `BirthdayContract.Contacts.NAME`. I believe you need to provide more information and/or updated examples which compile and demonstrate the issue you are seeing. Thanks.

Comment: @mfulton26 I did the same thing - created new .kt file, and copied my Kotlin code inside. It compiles without errors. There was no problem with BaseColumns interface. What kind of error do you have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NAME` is a property and by default its backing field has private access. But since it's a property, there's a getter for it: `getNAME()`.

Since this is not how you naturally access constants in Java, there are a couple ways to directly expose the field:

1. [`const`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#compile-time-constants): `const val NAME = "Name"`
2. [`@JvmField`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-field/) annotation: `@JvmField val NAME = "Name"`

Comment: @JvmField works nice for me, thanks! However, "const" and "@JvmStatic" don't affect anything.

Answer (score 2):

To expose constants as fields, annotate them with `@JvmField`

```
class Contacts  {
    companion object {
        @JvmField val NAME = "Name"
        @JvmField val BIRTH = "Birth"
        @JvmField val IMAGE = "Image"
    }
}
```

Then you can use them from Java like this:

```
String name = Contacts.NAME;
```

Once all of your code is in Kotlin, you can remove the @JvmField annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using plain **object** as this.:

```
object Contract {
    object Contacts {
        val NAME = "Name"
        val BIRTH = "Birth"
        val IMAGE = "Image"
    }
}
```

This should perfectly fill in for your initial Java-Code.

In the most recent stable Kotlin-Version **public** is the default visibility.

Optionially you can add the **const** key-word for compile time constants so that they are usable in annotations.: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#compile-time-constants

**@JvmStatic** annotation is for Java-Interop and if you plan to go full kotlin you won't need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a @JvmStatic

```
object BirthdayContract {
    class Contacts : BaseColumns {
        companion object {
            @JvmStatic val NAME = "Name"
            @JvmStatic val BIRTH = "Birth"
            @JvmStatic val IMAGE = "Image"
        }
    }
}

//Java
BirthdayContract.Contacts.Companion.getNAME()
```

So far I see no good reason to extend BaseColumns, so a better choice whould be

```
object BirthdayContract {
    object Contacts  {
           const val NAME = "Name"
           const val BIRTH = "Birth"
           const val IMAGE = "Image"

    }
}
//Java
BirthdayContract.Contacts.NAME
```

The bottom line is that nested objects in kotlin do not look clean.
Please consider simplifying your code

Comment: BaseColumns have ID and COUNT, I think that's the reason why noktigula extend it.